# XLPagerTabStrip Button Bar width wider than navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, xlpagertabstrip

I am implementing a ButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController with two buttons on my navigation controller's navigation bar. I followed the example provided by adding the following into viewDidLoad()

```
self.buttonBarView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
self.settings.style.buttonBarItemsShouldFillAvailableWidth = true
self.buttonBarView.removeFromSuperview()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(buttonBarView)
```

However when the Button Bar loads in the navigation bar the width of the Button Bar exceeds the width of the navigation bar. This leaves me with the following:

[image: navbar image]

How can I fix this so that all the buttons fill the width of the navigation bar but do not exceed the width of the navigation bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connecting the containerView outlet to a UIScrollView in Interface Builder fixed this problem for me.